# regex lazy quantifier

Tags: regex

Suppose I have string `Heeello`. Can someone tell my why the regex `/H(e+)llo/` and the regex `/H(e+?)llo/` return the same group `eee` although first is greedy and the second is lazy (so it should return `e`)?

Comment: Still waiting for a more detailed answer, or could you please accept the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

lazy is based on the following pattern. `H(e+?)llo`, here the following character is `l`, so inorder to find a match it would match all the e's until the `l` is reached.

Just remove the following `llo` from the above regex. Now it would capture the first `e` only. Since we removed the following pattern `llo` (ie, the pattern next to the lazy quantifier), it must capture the first `e`.

Consider `Heeee` as the input string and `H(e+?)` as the regex pattern.

`H` matches the letter `H` and `e+?` will do a non-greedy match of one or more `e`'s. So this would match only `He`, because it finds the match  after the first attempt. Here there is no following pattern.

Consider `Heeeello` as the input string and `H(e+?)llo` as the regex pattern.

Here `H` matches the first `H` and at first `e+?` matches the first `e`. Because the pattern is not complete yet, the regex engine picks up the third next pattern that is, `l`. In-order to find a match, regex engine matches all the `e`'s upto the letter `l` .

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW6jU8/7)

These two regexes will do the same job. You dont need to use the non-greedy form.

```
^.*$
^.*?$
```

Comment: So when the pattern doesn't end with a quantifier, this quantifier will never work as lazy?

Comment: yep, `.+` is greedy which matches any character as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The lazy regex try to find a match with the less effort possible. 
If you would have to match *heeee* with */H(e+?)/*, you would get just he. And with */H(e+)/*, *heeee*.

But as the sequence of *e* have to be followed by *llo*, even the lazy regex have to capture all the *e* to find *llo*.